# Expect script - expecting 2 conditions and extracting a MAC add from bluetoothctl

Tags: linux, bluetooth, tcl, expect

I'm working off a raspberry pi zero w with bluetooth on board. Currently I can use bluetoothctl to manually do what I want but I'm trying to automate this so the rpi can be left alone to do this task for weeks at a time.

The goal is have the rpi be discoverable in bluetooth and let someone connect to it automatically without a password. Once the connection is established I want to send the info command to that paired mac address to retrieve more information about the device. Eventually I'd like to add in functionality to be able to send a text file to the device (laptop, android phone, etc) but that can come later. Ultimately I want to log the info (mac and info results with a timestamp) in a separate file.

Let me state I have very limited knowledge in this but am trying to make it happen. If you have any ideas about how to proceed that may be easier I'm all ears. Currently I've been developing an expect script to do this job. So far I have this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set prompt "#"
log_user 1
set timeout -1
send_user "Please enter bluetooth signal name: "
expect_user -re "(.*)\n"
set btname $expect_out(1,string)
send_user "BT signal will be $btname\n"

send_user "\nEnter Log Name: "
expect_user -re "(.*)\n"
set logname $expect_out(1,string)
send_user "You entered $logname\n"
log_file -a $logname

sleep 2

spawn sudo bluetoothctl
sleep 2
expect -re $prompt
send "system-alias $btname\r"
sleep 2
expect -re $prompt
send "scan on\r"
sleep 8
expect -re $prompt
send "discoverable on\r"
sleep 2
expect
```

So my problem is that when a device pairs the following is what signals this:

```
[bluetooth]# discoverable on
Changing discoverable on succeeded
[CHG] Controller B8:27:EB:03:68:F1 Discoverable: yes
[NEW] Device F8:F1:B6:E2:BB:06 DROID RAZR M
[CHG] Device F8:F1:B6:E2:BB:06 Modalias: bluetooth:v0008pB02Dd0000
[CHG] Device F8:F1:B6:E2:BB:06 UUIDs: 00001103-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device F8:F1:B6:E2:BB:06 UUIDs: 00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device F8:F1:B6:E2:BB:06 UUIDs: 00001106-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device F8:F1:B6:E2:BB:06 UUIDs: 0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device F8:F1:B6:E2:BB:06 UUIDs: 0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device F8:F1:B6:E2:BB:06 UUIDs: 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device F8:F1:B6:E2:BB:06 UUIDs: 00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device F8:F1:B6:E2:BB:06 UUIDs: 00001116-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device F8:F1:B6:E2:BB:06 UUIDs: 0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device F8:F1:B6:E2:BB:06 UUIDs: 0000112d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device F8:F1:B6:E2:BB:06 UUIDs: 0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device F8:F1:B6:E2:BB:06 UUIDs: 00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device F8:F1:B6:E2:BB:06 UUIDs: 00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device F8:F1:B6:E2:BB:06 UUIDs: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device F8:F1:B6:E2:BB:06 UUIDs: 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device F8:F1:B6:E2:BB:06 UUIDs: 453994d5-d58b-96f9-6616-b37f586ba2ec
[CHG] Device F8:F1:B6:E2:BB:06 UUIDs: 936da01f-9abd-4d9d-80c7-02af85c822a8
[CHG] Device F8:F1:B6:E2:BB:06 ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device F8:F1:B6:E2:BB:06 Paired: yes
[CHG] Device F8:F1:B6:E2:BB:06 ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device F8:F1:B6:E2:BB:06 Connected: no
[bluetooth]# info F8:F1:B6:E2:BB:06 
Device F8:F1:B6:E2:BB:06
    Name: DROID RAZR M
    Alias: DROID RAZR M
    Class: 0x5a020c
    Icon: phone
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: no
    Blocked: no
    Connected: no
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: Dialup Networking         (00001103-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: OBEX Object Push          (00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: OBEX File Transfer        (00001106-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Source              (0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Headset AG                (00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: NAP                       (00001116-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Handsfree Audio Gateway   (0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: SIM Access                (0000112d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Phonebook Access Server   (0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Message Access Server     (00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Vendor specific           (453994d5-d58b-96f9-6616-b37f586ba2ec)
    UUID: Vendor specific           (936da01f-9abd-4d9d-80c7-02af85c822a8)
    Modalias: bluetooth:v0008pB02Dd0000
```

So my question is- how can I make an "expect" that will either check for a regex of a valid MAC and the string "Paired: yes" and pull that MAC out of the buffer. Can I make an expect of "expect ( regex && string "Paired: yes") { do}"? I'm a little lost on how to do this and pull the actual MAC to save it to a variable and use it in the next info command. I'm guessing it's manipulating the expect_out(buffer) but this is way above my skill set.

Answer (score 0):

You ask how to pull some information out of the data matched by expect. Yet you do exactly that in the first part of your script where you obtain input from the user.

Now that part can be done simpler using gets. But when receiving data from bluetoothctl, using expect_out(#,string) to pick out relevant parts works very well.

Also, there is no reason for all those sleep commands if you just expect the right things.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

# Use command-line arguments if provided
lassign $argv btname logname

# Prompt for any missing arguments
if {$argc < 1} {
    send_user "Please enter bluetooth signal name: "
    gets stdin btname
}
send_user "BT signal will be $btname\n"

if {$argc < 2} {
    send_user "\nEnter Log Name: "
    gets stdin logname
}
log_file -a $logname

set prompt "#"
spawn bluetoothctl

expect -ex $prompt
send "system-alias $btname\r"
expect -ex "Changing $btname succeeded"

expect -ex $prompt
send "power on\r"
expect -ex "Changing power on succeeded"

expect -ex $prompt
send "scan on\r"

expect -ex $prompt
send "discoverable on\r"

expect {
    -timeout 120
    -re {Device ([0-9A-F:]+) Paired: yes} {
        # Get info on newly paired device
        expect -ex $prompt
        send "info $expect_out(1,string)\r"
    }
    -re {Controller ([0-9A-F:]+) Discoverable: no} {
        # Re-arm discoverability
        send "discoverable on\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    timeout {
        exit 1
    }
}

expect -ex $prompt
# Device info is now available in $expect_out(buffer)
```